# FLEX scanner- unable to return the correct token number

Tags: flex-lexer

```
%option noyywrap
%{
#include<stdlib.h>
#define INTEGER 1
#define PLUS 2
struct data
{
    int value;
}dataObj;
%}
%%
[0-9]+ dataObj.value=atoi(yytext);return INTEGER;
[+] return PLUS;
%%
int main()
{
    int ret_value;
    while(ret_value = yylex() !=0)
    printf("value:%d \t token type:%d\n",dataObj.value,ret_value);
}
```

if i use expression 3+5 it is giving value of 3 and 5 as 1 which is correct but it is giving the value of [+] as 1 rather it should be 2. i am using flex version 2.5.4

Comment: while( (ret_value=yylex() ) != 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you explained, but not very clearly, in your comment, the fault is in the while loop. If you run your code as originally posted, using the debug enabled in flex, the following output is produced:

```
--(end of buffer or a NUL)
3+5
--accepting rule at line 13 ("3")
value:3          token type:1
--accepting rule at line 14 ("+")
value:3          token type:1
--accepting rule at line 13 ("5")
value:5          token type:1
--accepting default rule ("
")

--(end of buffer or a NUL)
--EOF (start condition 0)
```

If however, the main program is changed to this:

```
int main()
{
    int ret_value;
    while((ret_value = yylex()) !=0)
    printf("value:%d \t token type:%d\n",dataObj.value,ret_value);
}
```

The following output is generated, which is correct:

```
--(end of buffer or a NUL)
3+5
--accepting rule at line 13 ("3")
value:3          token type:1
--accepting rule at line 14 ("+")
value:3          token type:2
--accepting rule at line 13 ("5")
value:5          token type:1
--(end of buffer or a NUL)
```

Your fault, as you surmised is a typo in the main program.

Comment: Yes @Brian that was a typo error , things to do how operator are resolved in C++ . so there should be proper parenthesis in while loop as i mentioned in comment !!